# How to debug Meteor unit test in WebStorm?

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, webstorm, angular-meteor

I was following [Meteor's Angular testing guide](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/testing) and it told me to run unit test by using this command:

```
meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha
```

I'm using WebStorm to edit my Meteor code, so I want to know is there any way to run/debug unit test in WebStorm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Running tests**

You have to make a [Run/Debug Configuration in Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) for Meteor.
You'll have to set the program arguments correctly:

`test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha`

You run the tests by running this configuration.

**Debugging tests client-side**

You can use the previous configuration and debug using the browser's console.

**Debugging tests server-side**

Make a new Meteor configuration with arguments:

`test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha --debug-port 5858`.

Running this configuration you'll see an output similar to:

> W20170409-20:19:21.287(2)? (STDERR) Debugger listening on [::]:5959

You can then debug the code by browsing to: http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5959

**Note:** in my case the port in the console differs from the port in the configuration. I have to use that port in the url.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have a long without using meteor, but seems your answer is quite make sense.